# jQuery: infinite loop process

Tags: javascript, jquery

The thing is to do an infinite loop that iterates over a certain object (passing images, changing background color, etc). When I call the function back:

```
function helloworld() {
    alert("hello, world!");
    helloworld();
}
```

the browser says that it has been done too many times. So i don't understand how the slideshows do. How can I call back a function infinitely so it doesn't breaks? (Of course, I'd set a setTimeout, otherwise it's too fast)

Comment: What do you mean that setTimeout is too fast?

Comment: No, I mean that without it it'd be very fast for it to be a visual process, @GreatBigBore

Comment: Do you mean that setTimeout is too slow?

Comment: No, just that after having the thing, I would add settimeout for it to pass at the right speed, nothing but that, :) that's not important, I just want the code

Comment: You're calling `helloworld()` immediately instead of delaying the execution with a `setTimeout`. You should do `setTimeout(helloworld, 2000)` for example to use a 2 second delay. Or use `setInterval()` and get rid of the recursive call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to call `helloworld` infinitely as fast as possible, write a loop:

```
while(true) {
    helloworld();
}
```

Note that this will prevent your program being externally notified of any other input or events going on. You will have to write extra code in your loop to check what's going on in the outside world. If you want to call `helloworld` infinitely at some controlled rate (and allow your program to process other events), use `setInterval`:

```
var theIntervalHandle = setInterval(helloworld, someDelayValue);

function helloworld() {
    // whatever

    if(readyToStopCallingHelloWorld) {
        clearInterval(theIntervalHandle);
    }
}
```

***Edit***: in case you're interested in technical details, note that it's not really recursive. Recursion is what you were doing in your original example, and you will eventually run out of stack space, as your browser told you. These examples are just calling `helloworld` over and over, not recursing into it. If you're interested, you might want to [read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) about recursion.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde Whoops, I misunderstood. I thought you didn't understand about recursion. I realize now that you do. I will leave the edits there in case anyone else finds them useful.